# Regex to match cid for Email Signature Image

Tags: email, outlook, exchangewebservices, email-attachments, email-validation

I have a scenario where the signature images in the mail content alone needs to be removed. EWS converting all the email attachments with Content and assigning it CID which are embedded in mail.

Here in the email, lot of images are embedded but I need to figure out only the signature image in the email body and needs to remove it.

It does only have CID and nothing to figure out to identify the signature image. Is there any possibility?

Signature Image:

> [cid:image001.jpg@01C451FD.99CD7240]

Some Other Image:

> [cid:image001.png@01D2C230.B44CH170]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking if signatures have a CID which can programmatically be distinguished from other CIDs? The answer is no.

There may be hints in other MIME headers like a `Content-Description: signature` or similar, but nothing is properly standardized. It's just another MIME part, and entirely optional.

There are weak heuristics you could use, like "if this is the last inline part, and/or it's identical to an inline body part in other messages from the same correspondent", but this is obviously brittle and error-prone.

Comment: Thank you! Then I will find some way to find with Regex? Does it help?

Comment: I don't understand your question. If there is no way to distinguish these programmatically then distinguishing them by regex is one of many methods which will not work.

Comment: "if this is the last inline part, " - As you said I thought of doing with Regex

Comment: If your programming language of choice lets you do that conveniently, by all means use regex. I don't think I have seen a MIME email representation which could be robustly and conveniently manipulated as a string, though. In particular, you usually cannot know which MIME part headers are present, or in which order. Also, inline-ness is often implicit. Many MIME features can be expressed in multiple ways. These facts tend to make it hard to operate on MIME messages using regex, even if you preprocess the message to normalize the representation.